# First time getting car finance, but existing car in my wife's name

Tags: united-kingdom, car

Our current situation is that we’ve always had our sole family car registered in my wife’s name, and insured in her name with me as an extra driver.

However, we’re planning on buying a new car with finance, and the finance terms require it to be taken out in the name of the registered keeper. My wife is a stay-at-home mum with little income, so I’m concerned we won’t be able to take finance out in her name.

How should we approach this situation with insurance, no claims bonus, etc? Currently our thinking is that we’d have register the new car in my name, cancel our existing insurance half way through its term, take out fresh insurance without any ncb in my name. Is there a better/cheaper way?

Comment: Consider having a chat with your insurance company. They might be able to tell you definitively, including how much the premiums would be in each case.

Comment: It might be possible that the registered keeper and the insurance partner are different, or that insurance bonus can be transferred to somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a requirement (of most insurance companies anyway) that the main driver has to be the registered keeper. It is often an "additional option" (i.e. a "we've made these assumptions, click here if they're not right").

Talk to your existing insurance company; they will probably be able to transfer your existing insurance over to the new car (for an admin fee and possibly an increased or decreased premium), keeping your wife as the main driver.